# Adding user inputs together in node.js/ javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to do shopping list with node that asks the user the product and the price. Then it needs to show the most expensive and cheapest product. I know how to get the price and the cheapest and most expensive values, but can't seem to figure out how I can add the product and price together.

Here is basically the raw version I have:

```
let array = [];

const mainfunc = () => {
  rl.question("add price : ", (aa) => {
    array.push(aa);
    console.log("---");
    console.log("Product " + aa + " added");
    console.log("added products " + array);
    console.log("Most expensive " + Math.max(...array));
    console.log("Cheapest " + Math.min(...array));
    console.log("---");
    mainfunc();
  });

};

mainfunc();
```

This is basically what I want the program to ask and give simplified:

```
Give product 1: Banana
Give price: 1
Give product 2: Apple
Give price: 2
Give product 3: Pear
Give price: 3

Most expensive item: Pear 3
Cheapest item: Banana 1
```

It only needs to work on node.js command line and it doesn't have to be fancy. I'm just stuck with it.

Comment: If you're using an array of objects { item_name, item_price }, you can sort them by item_price then the first and last objects would be the cheapest and most expensive respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can store product and price in an array of objects.

For example:

```js
const productPrices = []

productPrices.push({
  productName: "ABC",
  price: 20
})

productPrices.push({
  productName: "XYZ",
  price: 30
})

// Find product having max price
productPrices[productPrices.indexOf(Math.max(...productPrices(p => p.price)))]

// Find product having cheapest price
productPrices[productPrices.indexOf(Math.min(...productPrices(p => p.price)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const util = require('util');
const readline = require('readline');

const cli = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
const question = util.promisify(cli.question).bind(cli);

const PRODUCTS_COUNT = 4;
const productQuestions = ['Give product', 'Give price: '];
const answers = [];
let tmp = {};

const questions = [...Array(PRODUCTS_COUNT * 2)]
    .map((_, index) => index % 2 ? productQuestions[1] : `${productQuestions[0]} ${index / 2 + 1}: `)
    .map((item, index) => () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const answer = await question(item);

            if ( index % 2 ) {
                tmp.price = Number(answer);
                answers.push(tmp);
                tmp = {};
            } else {
                tmp.product = answer;
            }

            resolve();
        } catch {
            reject();
        }
    }));

(async () => {
    for ( const question of questions ) {
        await question();
    }

    console.log(answers);
    process.exit(0);
})();
```

[image: Execution result]